# CSS background disappears when using float:left

Tags: html, css, css-float

This is my html:

```
<div class="header_wrapper">
       <div class="main_nav">
       <div>TEst</div>
       <div>TEst</div>
       <div>TEst</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see I want to build a menu with floating divs. Doing so the background of main_nav disappears.

```css
.header_wrapper{

    height:129px;
    background:url('images/layout/header.png') no-repeat #1f1f1f;
    border-bottom:1px solid #1f66ad
}

.header_wrapper .main_nav{
    position:relative;
    top:77px; left:336px;
    width:750px;
    background:red;
}

.header_wrapper .main_nav div{
    float:left;
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

I tried to use clear:both, however the background is still gone. Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you try to assign height?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Adding `overflow:auto;` to main_nav brings the background back.

Comment: Using _overflow:auto;_ can cause  problems in some browsers like scroll bar may appear/disappear, or the content area my cut off

Answer (score 10):

This is because floated content **does not take up any space**. Your parent `main_div` division essentially takes on a height of 0 because it has no other content, which "hides" the background (there is no height to display behind).

This information is available in the [css-floating tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css-floating/info) and I've also posted other [more detailed information about floating and parent containers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9447057/246246).

Comment: He said, _"background of `main_nav` disappears"_, not the background of `header_wrapper`.  His `header_wrapper` should not be collapsed since he's included a clearing `div` within.

Comment: @Sparky672: Thanks, just a matter of changing the name of the div in my post...

Comment: And it's not the parent.

Comment: @Sparky672: It is the parent of the divisions in it.

Comment: Yes, it's the parent of something... but it's clearly not the parent of what he's asking about, it's the target.

Answer (score 4):

Put `overflow` on `.main_nav`

```
.header_wrapper .main_nav div{
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Your clearing `div` forces its parent to expand, it has no effect on its sibling's background.

Answer (score 3):

You have to `clear` to your `float DIV'`s parent which is `.main_nav`. Write like this:

```
.header_wrapper .main_nav{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```