# Set height 100% but css div does not expand

Tags: html, css

I have experimented with CSS and found one problem. According to my code (http://jsbin.com/daguviluwo/1/edit?html,output), I would like to create two boxes with "float:left" which automatically adjust their heights to be equal (=the maximum height). Therefore, I create their parent(id="content"). I thought that the parent's height should be adjusted according to the maximum height of its children (but it is not!). Then, the children with property "height:100%" (red box) should have the height as the same as this parent and also the same as the child with maximum height (green box). However, it does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446988/expanding-the-parent-container-with-100-height-to-account-for-floated-content

please follow this link

Comment: use position: absolute; but this will ruin your layout :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `display property value` of **`inline-flex`** to:

- **`#content`**
- **`#leftcontent`**
- **`#rightcontent`**

Also add `size property value` of **`height:auto`** to:

- **`#leftcontent`**
- **`#rightcontent`**

```css
#content {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 500px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
}
#leftcontent {
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-flex;
}
#rightcontent {
  background-color: green;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="leftcontent">
      <ul>
        <li>The height of this div is set to 100</li>
        <li>List 2</li>
        <li>List 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="rightcontent">
      <h2>This is my first header.</h2>
      <p>Content.</p>
      <h2>This is my second header.</h2>
      <p>Content 2.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Note:** With this approach, you can remove the floats from left/right element CSS

Answer (score 0):

When you use `float` on an element, that element leaves the normal flow of the content, and its height does not count as far as its parent element is concerned.

**Example**

If you have a parent element, and an only child element which has `float: left;` and `height: 300px;`, then the parent element will act as if it does not have a child at all and its height will be 0px (or more if it has paddings, but we assume it does not). If the child did not have `float` then the parent would have `height: 300px` as you'd expect.

There is a trick that 'corrects' this kind of behaviour which makes it so that even if a child element has `float` its height still counts for its parent.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Now, regarding the `height:100%` of the children, this will only work if the parent has a declared `height` other than `auto` which is the height it has if you do not declare one.

**Example**

If the parent has `height:300px` and you set the child to have `height:100%` it will also be 300px then. But if the parent has not a declared height (i.e. it has `height: auto`) the child will have a height of 0px (or more if it has paddings, but we assume it does not)